# Understand behaviour of low memory killer

Tags: android, memory-management

When a low memory killer runs, and suppose if it kills an app, does it remove the app from recents screen too? And how to mock the functionality of low memory killer? Like in a device, I want to test, when the low memory killer runs. Please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not remove the app from recents screen. It only clears all the memory related to app. It is done as recents panel does not use that much memory, and user can keep track of what apps he used. So next time the user clicks on the killed app from recents panel, it is relaunched from start.

If you want to mock the functionality of low memory killer, you can simply run heavy apps and games on the device and see if it kills your app.